# Refresh a tab on a browser (Python)

Tags: python

My program opens a certain page on using

```
webbrowser.open(url)
```

How is it possible to reload the tab containing the url several times?
I could use `sleep` to set the time limit in which it has to wait before it has to reload.
But how do I refresh the tab after that? (Not open it in a new tab.)

Comment: Webbrowser might not be the best module for that - you might investigate [selenium and webdriver](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html), which is vastly more powerful (though you might have to install some extra stuff).

Comment: Selenium worked out for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** below is my OLD answer, I'm not deleting it because it shows the ambiguity in the docs, and could possibly serve as a learning experience to someone.

If you read the docs, they make it sound like its possible. However, it is not possible to do with this module, further more, it seems like no matter what option you give to "new" it always opens in a new tab. Perhaps this behavior is specific to my system, or browser(IE9) but I believe it is more likely a bug in the program.

I investigated further, there is questions about this all over SO. you can't do it with webbrowser or anything built into python.

If you install selenium, you should be able to do what you want.

I am assuming you don't have access to the source code of this webpage, otherwise, you could just use html to do the refresh. If you don't want to install selenium and don't have source access, then you need to make a wrapper for the webpage, and use HTML/JS to refresh the wrapper.

---

[the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) say:

webbrowser.open(url, new=0, autoraise=True)

Display url using the default browser. If new is 0, the url is opened in the same browser window if possible. If new is 1, a new browser window is opened if possible. If new is 2, a new browser page (“tab”) is opened if possible. If autoraise is True, the window is raised if possible (note that under many window managers this will occur regardless of the setting of this variable).

so... 
to refresh the page, it would just be:

```
for i in range(refresh_limit):
    time.sleep(wait_time)
    webbrowser.open(url)
```

^^^ this does not actually work^^^

Comment: Lets say that the tab opens, then the user switches to a new tab while the process is waiting. Will this refresh the correct tab, or override the tab that the user is on?

Comment: I don't know, I have never used the module, but that is not within the scope of this question. Why the downvote?

Comment: Can somebody explain what is wrong with this answer? I don't see why it deserves down votes.

Comment: Wouldn't this keep opening up NEW tabs with the same URL? I wanted the SAME tab to keep refreshing.

Comment: I'm going to make a new answer. The docs, make it sound like it will open it in the same tab, but it just means same WINDOW, new tab. That renders the new=2 completely useless, but i didn't write the module. long story short u need to use a new module, webbrowser wont do what you want

Comment: I tried this but it kept opening the new tabs with same url ? Did it work for you ? Which browser are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would be possible to implement a pure python solution for this which works with different browsers. A solution I would think of is using JavaScript. Vaguely the idea is to create a html file which has an iframe with the url you want and has javascript for reloading the iframe in regular interval. Then use webbrowser module to open that file.

This may sound ugly but this may be the only solution given the security concerns of a browser.

*If you are interested with this idea I can help you writing the code for this.
Hope this helps.